# How to perform addition in text file bypassing strings

Tags: python-3.x, csv, math, sum, addition

I converted my csv file to text file and I want to add the numbers inside the text file. When I run my code get an error. Assuming the error code I want to write logic that would bypass my strings and just add the numeric values.

```
`import csv 
csv_file = 'Annual Budget.csv'
txt_file = 'annual_budget.txt'
with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
with open(csv_file, 'r') as my_input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_input_file)
    for row in reader:
        my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n')

        data = []
with open(r'annual_budget.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    fields = line.split()
    rowdata = map(float, fields)
    data.extend(rowdata)
print(sum(data)/len(data)
```

Output (Error): `data.extend(rowdata)
ValueError: could not convert string to float Value: 'ANNUAL'`

Here are the contents of my text file :

```
ANNUAL BUDGET Q2 Q4

100 450 20

600 765 50

500 380 79

800 480 455

1100 65 4320
```

Comment: The error gives you the problem. Just skip the first line.

Comment: @BaileyKocin Skip the first line of my text file?

Comment: @Pradam answered it but you are trying to convert the string 'ANNUAL' to a float. How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code as mentioned below:

```
  with open(r'annual_budget.txt', 'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     headers = reader.next() # this will yield first row i.e columns if python 3: Use next(reader) instead of reader.next()
     for line in reader:
         rowdata = map(float, line)
         data.extend(rowdata)
     print(sum(data)/len(data))
```

Comment: This gives me  "print(sum(data)/len(data)
                               
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" Why is my logic doing that?

Comment: Add a right parenthesis to the end of that last line.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thank you I just noticed that. Now I have an attribute error. "AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: @Pradam almost there!!! code is still throwing error and it has to do with the headers = reader.next() line it throws: "header = reader.next()
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'"

Comment: @AnthonyHarmon if python 3: Use next(reader) instead of reader.next()

Comment: @Pradam Indeed I am using Python 3, using next(reader) put me back to square one. Instead of error "Annual could not be converted to string" I am now getting "data.extend(rowdata)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:"

Comment: @Anthony Harmon in your loop check if the line contains anything before converting. The blank lines cant be converted to numbers.

Comment: @BaileyKocin no space before the strings in my text file and my loop seems to be valid.